# How to forward libnotify to growl

Tags: notifications, forwarding, libnotify

I'm looking for a simple solution to forward `libnotify` notifications (from knotify4) to a remote growl servers (running on Windows and Android).

So far I'm only able to send remote growl notifications from the command line (using `gntp-send` or [this python lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gntp/))

The [Growl for linux](http://mattn.github.io/growl-for-linux/) implementation is only able to forward the opposite way (growl->libnotify), and does not allow remote notifications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found it is possible to do that with a [python script connected to the local dbus server as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89279/listening-to-incoming-libnotify-notifications-using-dbus) + the [gntp library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gntp).